Error: AADSTS900144 - Missing 'grant_type' Parameter in Request Body
I am encountering an issue while working with Azure Active Directory authentication. Specifically, I am receiving the following error message:
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.}
Here is the context of my request:
Endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Request Method: POST
Headers: "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Request Body:
{
  "grant_type": "client_credentials",
  "client_id": {client_id},
  "client_secret": {client_secret},
  "scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
}

Can someone please guide me on how to correctly include the 'grant_type' parameter in the request body? Any examples or insights into what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
I have ensured that the request body includes other necessary parameters, but the 'grant_type' parameter seems to be missing or incorrectly specified.

The error occurred as you are passing wrong Content-Type while generating the token.
Initially I got the same error:

I agree with @juunas, either change Content-Type to "application/json" and pass json data OR with Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded pass body as form-encoded POST parameters.
I passed the body as parameters like below to resolve the error:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANTID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default


Otherwise, you can also change the Content-Type to "application/json" and pass json data only

You specify: "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", but are sending JSON.
Change Content-Type to "application/json" or send form data.

it should be the other way around: the spec dictates "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", so the body should not be JSON but rather a sequence of form-encoded POST parameters
